# Python program query 1

Tags: python

I just had written few lines of code and below is the one:

```
def fun(x,y):
    op=input("Please enter the operator: ")
    if op=='*':
        y=y*x
    if op=='+':
        y=y+x
    if op=='-':
        y=x-y
    if op=='/':
        y=x/y
    return y


for n in range(1,999):
    if n==1:
        try:
            a=int(input("Please enter the value 1: "))
            b=int(input("Please enter the value 2: "))

            if a not in ('*','/','+','-') or b not in ('*','/','+','-'):
                f=fun(a,b)
                break
        except:
            print("Please enter the proper number")

        print(f)
```

The value of f has not printed, even though i have given correct input. is this because of exception clause.if so, what should we do to print values outside, when they are defined inside try/except clause.

Below is the output displayed.

```
Please enter the value 1: 1

Please enter the value 2: 2

Please enter the operator: *
```

Comment: you are breaking out of the for loop after getting an operator..

Comment: You don't need to test for all those operators (`a not in (...)`, etc), because `a` and `b` are *guaranteed* to be integers by that stage.

Comment: @Sayse Agreed, delete the `break`.

Comment: Just use `a = int(input(....))` and `b = int(input(...))` and `f = fun(a, b)`. Don't catch *all* exceptions, catch only `ValueError` and perhaps `ZeroDivisionError`, that way you can still use CTRL-C to end your program.

Comment: Maybe you only do this for debugging reasons or because you couldn't end your loop/program because of the catch-all, but having a loop and only doing stuff for one iteration (`if n==1`) makes little sense.

Answer (score 0):

just pull your print(f) command out of your for loop and it works:

```
for n in range(1,999):
    ...

print(f)
```

Comment: "it works" would depend on what the op expects the code to do, they may as well just remove the for loop if they only wanted to do math with 2 numbers

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `fun` after an `if` statement immediately after which a `break` statement is executed. That takes the control out of the loop.

Yet the `print` was inside the loop.

Hence, the `print` is not executed.

And I don't think you need that

```
if a not in ('*','/','+','-') or b not in ('*','/','+','-'):
```

Both `a` and `b` are integers so why compare them with strings?

And if that `break` statement is there, the loop would execute only once for correct input.

Something like

```
for n in range(1,999):
        try:
            a=int(input("Please enter the value 1: "))
            b=int(input("Please enter the value 2: "))

            f=fun(a,b)

        except:
            print("Please enter the proper number")
            break

        print(f)
```